# Git commit some staged changes ignoring unstaged

Tags: git

I added file changes to the staging area and after that make some other changes and want them to be untracked until first change is not commited (see the code below).

If I have one file, it can be done by simple `git commit`. But suppose if I have several different files staged and some of them not staged. When I point list of files `git commit <files>`, Git commits current contents of these files, i.e. untracked changes, ignoring staged ones.
But I want to commit staged changes ignoring untracked for some specific list of files. How to do that?

```
 (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   f1

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   f1
```

Comment: Why is this so difficult with git? Every other version control system I've used let's you check-in and "commit" whichever files you want, it doesn't stop you because you've been working on something else and aren't ready to commit it to the repository yet

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be your best bet:

```
git commit --interactive f1 f2
```

That should let you choose which hunks to commit from the list of files, but you'll have to go through each hunk individually and chooose whether to include it in your commit. Using something like emacs's magit plugin would make this much easier.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to commit staged changes ignoring untracked for some specific list of files

Not possible with `git commit`. If you commit the index, you commit the index.

I see to ways for you. Either you untrack the parts that you do not want to commit, yet. Since you are asking your question, I assume this is not possible (too many changes)?

The second variation is this: copy (important: do not clone) your local repository. *In the copy*, remove the parts from the index that you do not want. Commit and push (if you do not have a remote yet, then `git add remote origin original_repos`). In your original repository, do a `git stash` to clean your working directory, pull the change, then `git stash pop`.

(You can try to do a `git pull` without the stash, but I guess `git` will tell you that that would clobber your local changes right away.) With a bit of luck, you're now in business - maybe you have to do conflict resolution, but it should be straightforward.

Of course, make a backup before you do all of this.

Comment: What do you mean by "if you do not have a remote yet"? Our model is to fork the main repository on Github, then clone our fork, push up into our fork, then Pull Request on the main repository from our form. So we have two remote's, our fork, and the upstream main repository

Comment: Also how do you "remove the parts from the index you do not want"? Outside the scope of original question but what if I've already committed some files I don't want to push, can I remove them?